# App doesn't sideload when debugging with Teams Toolkit

Tags: visual-studio-code, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I'm trying to debug one of the tutorial apps with MS Teams Toolkit for VS Code on a Mac.

When I press F5, it opens a new Chrome window and loads Teams, this message appears:

```
App not found, Please verify the app and it's access permissions.
For more information, please visit aka.ms/teamsdocs
```

I followed the instruction to open my app (`https://localhost:3000/tab`) and allow the insecure connection, but it made no difference.

Also tried manually uploading the app through Teams -- it shows as installed but debugging still doesn't work.

The app works if I upload it through Teams as a custom app, just debugging does not.

Versions:

- VSCode 1.53.1
- Toolkit 1.1.8
- Teams for Mac 1.3.00.33671

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you side load the app in teams? to debug check if messaging endpoint is updated to new one or not

Answer (score 1):

If you're unable to see the side load option in the Apps menu, you may need to create a Teams account through the Microsoft 365 developer program, which you can find the steps to do so on the [Teams Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/prerequisites?tabs=vscode#get-a-free-teams-developer-tenant-optional).

If you are able to side load apps, then you may need to configure permissions to allow your account to debug local apps. Go to admin Teams panel and choose Teams apps > Setup policies ([or visit this shortcut](https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/policies/app-setup)). Click on Global and tick "Upload custom apps" to allow all users to upload local Teams apps. Remember to hit save!

If you want to specify which users can upload custom Teams apps, create a new policy that allows uploading custom apps, select said policy from the policies list, choose Manage users, and select the user you want to assign the policy to.

Comment: I have followed the steps you have mentioned but still the error is not resolving. Do you have any other solution?